# Nested / child articles

Tags: joomla-4.x

I'm very new to Joomla, and I suspect that what I'm trying to do is very straightforward but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it, which probably means I'm looking in the wrong place.

Let's say I'm building a Joomla 4 website to hold information about British Cities and current Premiership football clubs. In RDBMS terms we have a Cities table and a Clubs table and a zero to many relationship between the two.

What I'd like is to be able to display a City and then expanding sections within the City page, one for each Club. Some Cities don't have any Club - that's fine. Some may have several - also fine. I'd like to make this all data driven, so that the Clubs just have a FK-like CityID, (rather than putting links into each City listing all its Clubs and a link into each Club identifying its City).

I'd also like the Clubs to be independent entities at some level so that a user could search by Club/show all Clubs founded in 1890s, that kind of thing, rather than just data within the Cities entries.

- I think I should set up both Clubs and Cities as Articles within Joomla.
- I think I distinguish those Articles by having separate Categories for Clubs and Cities - I can create a few custom fields on each Category, so Clubs can have founding dates and Cities can have population sizes.

But...

- I don't know where to start with making the Clubs appear as nested "sub articles" within their Cities. In RDBMS this is a parent/child or master/detail form, but a few hours searching those kinds of terms in Joomla hasn't thrown anything useful up. The Clubs "sub articles" will need to be fully functioning articles, not just entries in a table, as they could include pictures, etc.

Any kind of steer much appreciated. E.g., is this do-able in native Joomla, is there a Module or Extension for it, is Joomla the right tool for this job.

Comment: I am confident that Joomla can handle this task, but this is a large, multipart question.  Questions that are this broad typically end in 2 ways: either with extremely vague advice or no answers at all.  If you need a developer, please find one and pay them.  Otherwise, try to narrow your question to a smaller piece of this task.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Even new users can accept answers.

Answer (score 1):

Categories and Articles are already a one-to-many relationship.  Hence, make each city a category (under a parent category called City), and place the information about the city in the category description.  Each club is an article assigned to a city category.  The main pages are category blog layout or lists with the city description at the top and the clubs listed or linked below.

As for making a search find all clubs founded in the 1890s that is about 7 times more complicated.

Comment: Hi James thank you very much - that was exactly the level of input I needed. Unfortunately I don’t have enough reputation points here to upvote your answer, so gratitude is all I can offer. The bit about finding all clubs founded in a certain time was  just to illustrate the point about the clubs being first class entities. The actual website is a really obscure subject matter - but Cities and Clubs gives exactly the right data model without needing lots of further explanation.